# Python common file operations generalization

Tags: python, python-3.x, functional-programming

Functions with common and simple file operations have started to repeat in my code. Many like this one, but with subtle differences for example:

```
def do_something_with_file(file_name, access_mode, data):
    with open(file_name, access_mode) as f:
        f.do_something(data)
```

This is my solution so far:

```
import pickle
from functools import partial


def _open_file(func, access_mode, file_name, *args, **kwargs):
    with open(file_name, access_mode) as f:
        return func(f, *args, **kwargs)


open_file = partial(_open_file, lambda f: f, 'r')

read_lines = partial(_open_file, lambda f: list(f), 'r')

write_lines = partial(_open_file, lambda f, d: f.writelines(d), 'w')

load_pickle = partial(_open_file, lambda f: pickle.load(f), 'rb')

save_pickle = partial(_open_file, lambda f, d: pickle.dump(d, f), 'wb')
```

Example usage:

```
write_lines('file.txt', data)
pickle = load_pickle('file.pickle')
```

It seems readable enough for simple tasks and more complicated function definitions could also be passed to partial instead of simple anonymous functions like above.

Does anyone see any drawbacks of using this or has suggestions on how it could be improved?

Comment: `Is anyone using a different approach?` Probably. Is that really what you want to know though? Best-practices questions don't do well on Code Review. We can review your code, not determine whether it's 'the best thing to do'.

Comment: You are right. I have edited my question.

Comment: Just wanted to check, `partial` is [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial)?

Comment: Yes. I've added the imports to the code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it works for you why not.

The definitions could be further simplified too:

```
read_lines = partial(_open_file, list, 'r')
load_pickle = partial(_open_file, pickle.load, 'rb')
```

And possibly also extract the first two repeated tokens:

```
__open_file = partial(partial, _open_file)
read_lines = __open_file(list, 'r')
load_pickle = __open_file(pickle.load, 'rb')
```

With a bit more metaprogramming that could be done in a loop too and
there are probably also ways to convert the other two lambdas using
something from the `operator` module or so.

You see where I'm going with this?
[Pointfree style](https://wiki.haskell.org/Pointfree) isn't exactly the
most readable after all (actually the comparison with Pointfree style
isn't the best, but it illustrates the point about combining functions
with combinators for decreased readability quite well).

If I saw this in production I'd probably say that you aren't gonna need
it.  While interesting there's simply not that much added value in
saving up the definitions IMO.

Also, how `with open(...)` etc. behaves is quite obvious - with these
definitions not so much.

The underscore on `_open_file` suggests a private function, which it
might not be, depending on your module layout.  It looks like a useful
enough combinator, so could also be exported for reuse.

`open_file` on the other hand looks useless:  What do you want to use a
*closed* file object for?

Biggest complaint:  There are no docstrings.  So, `help(_open_file)`
basically gives me the function signature, whereas `help(load_pickle)`
gives me the documentation for `partial` - which might be correct, but
is also completely useless.  In the interest of better understandable
code I'd probably not recommend to use this approach unless you figure
out a way to assign docstrings to those function-like objects (I could
find one with a quick search, but that doesn't mean there isn't one).

Answer (score 2):

The code is straighforward and reads good; there is not much to say per se. I would just advise to use `f.readlines` instead of `list(f)`.

However, there exist a pattern in Python when you need to wraps functions using a common behavior: decorators.

I suggest having a decorator taking the `open_mode` as parameter:

```
import pickle
from functools import wraps

def opening(access_mode='r'):
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(filename, *args, **kwargs):
            with open(filename, access_mode) as f:
                return func(f, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator

@opening()
def read_lines(file_):
    return file_.readlines()

@opening('w')
def write_lines(file_, data):
    file_.writelines(data)

@opening('rb')
def load_pickle(file_):
    pickle.load(file_)

@opening('wb')
def save_pickle(file_, data):
    pickle.dump(data, file_)
```

Usage is the same.